# Opening the Command Prompt in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

How can I open the command prompt in vs code? But as a window separate from vs code?
I tried shortcuts and other questions on StackOverflow but they all are on vs code and not opening it on a separate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do exactly what you are asking for. However, it sounds like you might be interested in installing Microsoft Terminal, available for free in the Microsoft Store. I use Microsoft Terminal Preview, it works extremely well.

Comment: Oh ok, uhhhh do you have a link for it?

Comment: Use your Windows key, then type `store`, Enter, search for **Microsoft Terminal**

Comment: ok thanks(I need 6 more characters before I can send this so I added this)